# File is locked after creating it with EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I create an Excel file using EPPlus library. After the file is created, it cannot be deleted or edited, as it is said to be used by "another user", as long as the program is running. I cannot find any solution that would work for me.

Here is my code:

```
        var newFile = new FileInfo(path); 
        using (var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
        {
            var ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
...
            xlPackage.Save();
        }
```

Comment: There's got to be some code in the `...` that's leaving a resource open. You have the `ExcelPackage` wrapped in a `using`; so that's not it. Unless of course there's a bug in the EPPlus library.

Comment: In "..." I just add cells with data and some styles. It can't be it. I suspect an error in the library, but wonder if there is any way around it.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `SaveAs` with a `FileStram` that can read/write;

```
using(var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using(var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
    var ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
    // ...
    xlPackage.SaveAs(stream);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not help... Plus also, the excel file is now said to be unreadable.

Comment: @DavidShochet: So the error remains? A quick test worked, at least there was no error for me.

Comment: Maybe your files are released after the execution ends. But I have my code in a service, so to release the files, I need to restart the service. Also, unlike before, when I try to open a file after it is not locked anymore, I get a message that the file is unreadable and if I want it to be recovered.

Comment: The strange thing is that I am able File.Delete() the newly created files from within my code. But I cannot delete or edit it while the program is still running from the Windows Explorer.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I was using filestream with filemode OpenOrCreate only.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I just came across this myself and found a solution if you are building the spreadsheet from a Data Table.

Dispose of the Data Table after you have saved the document i.e.

```
dt.Dispose();
```

This fixed my version of this problem

Answer (score 1):

I used the Image class in a  similar scenario and had to manually dispose the image with

```
img.Dispose();
```

regardless of the scope of the img variable before I could delete the file representing the img.